# Is there a way to create a rich GUI that possibly generates HTML code. Silverlight and WPF generate XAML code

Tags: javascript, html, wpf, silverlight, user-interface

I have a task/mini project to complete which is along the lines of GUI development.

**Things given to me**

A Visual Studio project (on top of which I am supposed to work) which is a HTML, JavaScript and CSS based web application project that does adding, deletion, editing data and other small tasks upon button clicks. But the GUI for this project is in the basic style containing simple buttons (e.g "Add", "Delete"), Text boxes and tables.

I have also been given an adobe illustrator file that contains the image of the expected rich GUI. **Image attached towards the end of this post**

**My task**

"Create a high-fidelity version of the application from the provided basic design (project) to match the expected concept design (the rich GUI expected)"

I am supposed to create a rich GUI (fancy looking) (by any method) and when I click the new GUI's buttons "Add", "Delete", it should call the javascript functions as in the original project.

**CAN SOMEONE TELL ME HOW DO I GET STARTED WITH THIS**

I thought of using Silverlight or WPF for creating the rich GUI but it generates xaml code. A HTML output will be of great help to me so that I can call the javascript functions.

What is the best approach to get this done. Thanks :)
HELP GREATLY APPRECIATED! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :) :) :)

[image]

Comment: this doesn't sound like it is related to wpf or silverlight at all. as far as I can tell this is HTML only

Comment: Hi Markus, could you look at the above picture that I added now and direct me as to how I can get started. Thank you very much.

Comment: First off you need to decide which route you want to go for your interface, HTML or Silverlight. That decision lies at the core, once you decide then we can talk implementation.

Comment: @KodeKreachor - Hi. I would prefer the HTML way (assuming it's the simpler way). Can you throw in your inputs to get this done using HTML approach? Thanks

Comment: Checkout my updated link below, I cleaned it up a bit and structured the CSS a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem, when designing the UI I like to begin with getting the basic layout of the controls wire-framed onto the page. Once the wireframe begins to take shape then I'll hook up my javascript events. It's recommended that you get your layout pretty much where you want it before you start fine-tuning your CSS branding.

Here's a quick starter wireframe for you: http://jsfiddle.net/KodeKreachor/8sPRx/5/

Answer (score 0):

You are able to call javascript functions from Silverlight.

In the html page:

```
function alertText(text) {
    alert(text);
}
```

In the Silverlight code:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("alertText", new string[] { "Hi!" })
```

You can read more here:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=298

Comment: That's assuming user356186 wants to use Silverlight at all, which they certainly don't have to. Needs to start by making the core strategic decision on which technology to use.

Comment: Hi, guys. Thanks for the help.

**I would love to go the HTML way. Can someone help me with this.**

@Peter - Thanks for your inputs on Silverlight. I would like to use HTML method first and have Silverlight as the last option. Thank you for your help.